# "code ." command doesn't work to open Visual Studio Code operator from mac terminal

Tags: visual-studio

**"code ." command doesn't work to open Visual Studio Code operator from mac terminal** I cannot open Visual Studio Code Editor from command line just by typing "code ." in terminal

[image: code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locate your bash profile with the command 'locate bash_profile'.That file is usually located in '/Users/user_name/.bash_profile'.Once you found the file, insert the following command.

```
"code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}"
```

After that, save the file and type the following command in the same directory.

See the attached screenshot for more clarity.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKUMx.png)

$source .bash_profile

Answer (score 32):

1. Launch VS Code
2. Open View --> Command Palette
3. Type `shell command` and

   find `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command` and install (for mac)

   find `Allow Workspace Shell Configuration` and install (for linux )
4. Restart the terminal
5. Go to your folder path and type `code .` in terminal.

Visual Code Studio will open with your current folder directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Pyae's answer, if you're running the Insider's version of VS code, you will need to use `code-insiders <command>` in order to use the command line utilities.

This is easily solved by adding an alias in your bash profile if you don't want to type the full program name every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my .bash_rc file based on Min Htet Oo's answer:

```
    export PATH="/Applications/Utilities/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/":$PATH
alias code='Electron'

code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```